# How do you set EMR Step Concurrency in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

Trying to set up an EMR Cluster using Cloudformation.

When you create it through the console there is an option for step concurrency. It is also in the aws cli, but I can't see it in Cloudformation anywhere.

Is it just not available, or am I missing something?

This is how it is done with the cli:

```
aws emr modify-cluster --cluster-id j-2AXXXXXXGAPLF --step-concurrency-level 10
```

Answer (score 1):

aws cli is api call in fact, and the setting of `StepConcurrencyLevel` is exist in EMR api reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyCluster.html

But cloudformation doesn't support all EMR api until the aws developers add the feature.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html

So if you can't find this option in cloudformation, you have to wait.